# Netdom Join Failed To Complete Successfully

Tags: windows, failed, active-directory

I have two servers on VMWare. One is a standard install of Server 2008 r2 and the other is Server 2008 core.

Server 2008's IP is: `192.168.186.135` and computer name is: `SERVER01`. This is a domain controller and has DNS installed along with Active Directory. The domain is called: contoso.com

Server 2008 Core's IP is: `192.168.186.137` and computer name is: `SERVER02`

They can both ping each other, but when I try running the following:

```
netdom join SERVER02 /domain:contoso.com
```

Results:

```
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The command failed to complete successfully.
```

I'm thinking it might be a DNS issue? I'm new to servers and I am teaching myself. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question needs a little more information:

I assume you have setup a domain called contoso.com and server01 is the domain controller ?

If you've followed any guide or similar, this should be the case, and you should also have setup server01 as a DNS server ?

If both of the above are complete, make sure server02 uses the IP-address of server01 as its only DNS server. You can run nslookup contoso.com on server02 and see if it can resolve the domain.

Edit: use netsh to set the ip/dns info on your NIC in server02 - first find which nics you have by running "netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces" - and then "netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver name="1" address=192.168.186.135 index=1" - replace name="1" with what info you got from the first command.

See http://www.shariqsheikh.com/blog/index.php/200804/how-to-setup-ip-configuration-of-windows-server-2008-server-core/comment-page-1/ or generel google info for more information on this.

Comment: Added more info to my original question. You were right, my domain is called contoso.com and SERVER01 is the DC. SERVER01 has DNS installed. I tried using NSLOOKUP but it says: 'Unknown can't find contoso.com'. How would I use the IP of SERVER01 as the only DNS server on SEVER02 core?

Comment: I updated my reply with more info

Comment: Excellent! This worked. Thanks so much. Basically, I ran the netsh command to show interfaces and my NIC (Local Area Connection) was showing as Index "21". So I used the following: netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver name="21" address=192.168.186.135 index="1" and it worked